# how to customer can create product in front-end?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I front-end magento 2.1 i created module for special account had create product. I try to extend `catalog_produc_form` in backend but not success. Any suggestion? thank advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your controller (On add to ) :

```
// instance of object manager - inject and get objectManager instance
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setSku('my-sku'); // Set your sku here
$product->setName('Product Name'); // Name of Product
$product->setAttributeSetId(4); // Attribute set id
$product->setStatus(1); // Status on product enabled/ disabled 1/0
$product->setWeight(10); // weight of product
$product->setVisibility(4); // visibilty of product (catalog / search / catalog, search / Not visible individually)
$product->setTaxClassId(0); // Tax class id
$product->setTypeId('simple'); // type of product (simple/virtual/downloadable/configurable)
$product->setPrice(100); // price of product
$product->setStockData(
                    array(
                        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                        'manage_stock' => 1,
                        'is_in_stock' => 1,
                        'qty' => 999999999
                    )
                );
// Adding Image to product
$imagePath = "sample.jpg"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks  @ronakchanuhan give time for my question.  just i mean get template of admin/catalog/product/new/set/4/type/simple in front-end. Method save i know.